How do I resolve the issue of my Angular application redirecting to a blank white screen after logging in?
When I attempt to implement lazy loading on my website as a beginner, I encounter an issue where after logging in, the login page redirects me to a blank white screen. How can I resolve this issue?
app-routing.moudle.ts
 const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: WebsiteLayoutComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        component: HomePageComponent // Home page component for website
      },
      {
        path: 'subcategory/:categoryId',
        component: SubcategoryPageComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'products',
        component: ProductPageComponent // Route for displaying search results
      },
      {
        path: 'product/:categoryId',
        component: ProductPageComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'product/:categoryId/:subcategoryId', // Route for products with subcategories
        component: ProductPageComponent
      },
      // Add other website routes here
    ]
  },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: 'swiper', component: SwiperComponent }, // Define a login route
  { 
    path: 'admin',
    loadChildren: () => import('./admin/admin.module').then(m => m.AdminModule),
    canActivate: [AuthGuard]
  },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '' }
];


@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }

admin-routing-module.ts :

const adminRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'admin',
    component: AdminLayoutComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    children: [
      { path: '', redirectTo: 'brand-list', pathMatch: 'full' },
      { path: 'brand-list', component: BrandListComponent },
      { path: 'category-list/:brandId', component: CategoryListComponent },
      { path: 'add-category', component: AddCategoryComponent },
      { path: 'edit-category/:id', component: EditCategoryDialogComponent },
      { path: 'edit-subcategory/:id', component: EditSubcategoryDialogComponent },
      { path: 'subcategory-list', component: SubcategoryListComponent },
      { path: 'bycategory/:id', component: SubcategoryListComponent },
      { path: 'products/:subcategoryId', component: ProductListComponent },
      { path: 'product/:id', component: ProductPageComponent },
      { path: '**', redirectTo: 'brand-list' }
    ]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(adminRoutes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AdminRoutingModule {}

Login.component.ts  :
export class LoginComponent {
  username: string = '';
  password: string = '';
  errorMessage: string = '';

  constructor(private authService: AuthService, private router: Router) {}

  async login(): Promise<void> {
    if (!this.username || !this.password) {
      this.showErrorMessage("Username and password are required.");
      return;
    }

    try {
      const loggedIn = await this.authService.login(this.username, this.password);
      if (loggedIn) {
        this.router.navigate(['/admin']);
      } else {
        this.showErrorMessage("Incorrect username or password.");
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error during login:", error);
      this.showErrorMessage("An error occurred during login.");
    }
  }

  showErrorMessage(message: string): void {
    this.errorMessage = message;
  }
}

after a successfull login i want login page to route me to /admin

Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?

Pretty sure the developer tools in the browser have the actual error you need to figure out to continue

okkey DarkBee i will take the advice

Right now you don't have /admin route in your app, but /admin/admin because of nesting. You should fix admin-routing-module.ts.
Instead of
const adminRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'admin',
    ...
  }
];

it should be just
const adminRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    ...
  }
];

